# React UseState not being updated

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, axios

I can't understand correctly how to update my useState. I'm receiving data via my Axios call so "applis" is not empty but it's the following that seems to stuck.

What I'm trying to do:

- Receive the data from the first call containing the list of applications (Name, ID, and the number of APIs that this application has)
- Take the ID of the applications to make a second call that will bring me the APIs for this application (thanks to the ID)
- All this when the application is loaded (I have 19 applications and more than a hundred APIs)

I can display in my Accordions my different applications but in AccordionSummary, you can see that I can't get my API list for an application.

Either I have nothing (as in this post) or all the APIs are under an application to loop over and over again ...

Here is my code :

```js
export default function documentationv2() {
    
    // Getteur - Setteur
    const [applis, setApplis] = useState([]);
    const [applicationSelect, setApplicationSelect] = useState([]);
    const [APIs, setAPIs] = useState([]);

    // Chargement
    const loadRessources = () => {
        axios.get('/api/documentation/application')
        .then((response) => {
            setApplis(response.data);
            console.log('LesApplications : ' + JSON.stringify(response.data))
            {applis.map((application) => (
                setApplicationSelect(application.IDAPPLI)
            ))}
            ListeAPI(applicationSelect);
            
        })
        .catch((error) => console.log(error));
    }
    
    const ListeAPI = (AppliID) => {
        console.log('SELECT : ' + AppliID)
        // console.log('ID : ' + AppliID)
        axios.get('/api/documentation/api?app_id=' + AppliID)
        .then((response) => {
            setAPIs(response.data)
            console.log('LesAPIS : ' + response.data)
        })
        {APIs.map((api, index) => (
            console.log('API : ' + api.api_uri)
        ))}
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('Chargement ....')
        loadRessources();
    }, [])

    // useEffect(() => {
    //     console.log('-> Application SELECT : ' + applicationSelect)
    //     axios.get('/api/documentation/api?app_id=' + 1)
    //     .then((response) => {
    //         setAPIs(response.data)
    //         console.log('-> APIs : ' + response.data)
    //     })
    // }, [applicationSelect])

    

    return (

            {/* -- BODY -- */}
            <Grid item className={classes.Body}>
                <Grid container className={classes.GridContainerBody}>
                    {applis.map((application, index) => (
                        <div className={classes.DivContainerBody}>
                            <Grid item className={classes.GridItemLeftBody}>
                                <Accordion key={application.IDAPPLI} onChange={(event) => setApplicationSelect(application.NOMAPPLI)} className={classes.AccordionBody}>
                                    <AccordionSummary expandIcon={<IconButton className={classes.ButtonBodyShow} disableRipple={true}><ExpandMoreIcon/></IconButton>}>
                                        <Typography>
                                            {application.NOMAPPLI} - ({application.NBAPI})
                                        </Typography>
                                    </AccordionSummary>
                                    <AccordionDetails className={classes.AccordionDetailsApplication}>
                                        
                                        {/* {ListeAPI(application.IDAPPLI)} */}
                                        {/* {APIs.map((api, index) => (
                                            <div className={classes.DivDetailsApplication}>
                                                <Accordion key={index} className={classes.AccordionBody}>
                                                    <AccordionSummary expandIcon={<IconButton className={classes.ButtonBodyShow} disableRipple={true}><ExpandMoreIcon/></IconButton>}>
                                                        <div className={classes.AccordionSumAPI}>
                                                            <Typography>
                                                                {api.api_uri}
                                                            </Typography>
                                                            <Typography>
                                                                {api.api_description}
                                                            </Typography>
                                                            <div className={classes.AccordionSumAPIDiv}>
                                                                <Chip
                                                                    style={{backgroundColor: "#06d6a0"}}
                                                                    label={api.api_version}
                                                                />
                                                                <Chip
                                                                    style={{backgroundColor: "#ffd166"}}
                                                                    label={api.api_response_type}
                                                                />
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div>
                                                                <Typography>
                                                                    Créé par {api.api_creation_user} le {api.api_date_creation}.
                                                                </Typography>
                                                                <Typography>
                                                                    Modifié par {api.api_maj_user} le {api.api_date_maj}.
                                                                </Typography>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </AccordionSummary>
                                                    <AccordionDetails>
                                                            <Typography>
                                                                Information
                                                            </Typography>
                                                    </AccordionDetails>
                                                </Accordion>
                                            </div>
                                        ))} */}
                                    </AccordionDetails>
                                </Accordion>
                            </Grid>

                            <Grid item className={classes.GridItemRightbody}>
                                <div>
                                    <Tooltip title="Mot de passe" placement="top" arrow>
                                        <IconButton 
                                            className={classes.ButtonHeader}
                                            disableRipple={true}
                                        >
                                            <LockIcon/>
                                        </IconButton>
                                    </Tooltip>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <Tooltip title="Télécharger doc
                                    " placement="top" arrow>
                                        <IconButton 
                                            className={classes.ButtonHeader}
                                            disableRipple={true}
                                        >
                                            <GetAppIcon/>
                                        </IconButton>
                                    </Tooltip>
                                </div>
                            </Grid>
                        </div>
                    ))}
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
            
        </Grid>
    )
}
```

What the different console.log tells me :

```
LesApplications : [{"NOMAPPLI" : "NameValue", "IDAPPLI" : "IdValue", "NBAPI" : "ValueCount"}, ...]

SELECT : 

LesAPIS :
```

Could someone explain my mistake? It must be something with the useEffect not re-rendering ? I don't really understand everything here.

Sorry in advance if the title of my question does not seem clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setApplis` is asyncronous, you can't call `applis.map` after `setApplis` because your `applis` isn't updated yet. You must call `applis.map` in `useEffect` with dependency on it. Then in second `useEffect` you call `ListeAPI(applicationSelect)` with actual `applicationSelect` array.

Example:

```
 const loadRessources = () => {
        axios.get('/api/documentation/application')
        .then((response) => {
            setApplis(response.data);
            console.log('LesApplications : ' + JSON.stringify(response.data))
        })
        .catch((error) => console.log(error));
 }

  useEffect(() => {
    const arr = applis.map((application) => application.IDAPPLI);
    setApplicationSelect(arr);
  }, [applis]);

  useEffect(() => {
   applicationSelect.length && ListeAPI(applicationSelect);
  }, [applicationSelect]);

  useEffect(() => {
    loadRessources();
  }, [])
```

Another example:

```
 const ListeAPI = (AppliID) => {
    axios.get('/api/documentation/api?app_id=' + AppliID)
    .then((response) => {
        setAPIs(prev => [...prev, ...response.data])
        console.log('LesAPIS : ' + response.data)
    })
}

 const loadRessources = () => {
        axios.get('/api/documentation/application')
        .then((response) => {
            setApplis(response.data);
            console.log('LesApplications : ' + JSON.stringify(response.data))
        })
        .catch((error) => console.log(error));
 }


 useEffect(() => {
     applis.length && applis.forEach((application) => ListeAPI(application.IDAPPLI));
  }, [applis]);

  useEffect(() => {
    loadRessources();
  }, [])
```

Example how to do correct `APIs` object sctructure:

```
const [APIs, setAPIs] = useState({});
const ListeAPI = (AppliID) => {
    axios.get('/api/documentation/api?app_id=' + AppliID)
    .then((response) => {
        setAPIs(prev => {
            return {
                ...prev,
                [AppliID]: response.data
            }
        })
    })
}
```

JSX, then you can find needed api by applis id:

```
{applis.map((application, index) => (
    ...

    {APIs[application.IDAPPLI] && APIs[application.IDAPPLI].map((api, index) => (
        ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply,  i will try this ! By the way, you don't need to put the loadRessources in the first useEffect as well ? So it can be mounted ?

Comment: Calling `loadRessources` in `useEffect` you need to do, but when you call `ListeAPI(applicationSelect);` you can check first `applicationSelect`  length. I edited answer.

Comment: Okay it seems to work ! But it at the part of 
   applicationSelect && ListeAPI(applicationSelect);
It's a 404 and it's "normal", the request need to take one by one the ID, and right now i'm sending everything like app_id = '1,2,3...'

Comment: Sorry, my bad , this is correct `applicationSelect.length && ListeAPI(applicationSelect);`

Comment: No problem :) Plus, it's not the missing .length that solve my problem. I need to find a way where is not putting every id in one request

Comment: You can iterate `applicationSelect` and call `ListeAPI` with each id

Comment: I edited answer, you can see second example, in this case `applicationSelect` useless and also you must change `setAPIs` call

Comment: Oh thanks you so much ! I even got the API now thanks to your help. Only need now is to display them nicely ! :D

Comment: Always happy to help )))

Comment: Can I ask you one more thing ? It's actually for the display. The objective of all of this is to display something like this : Name of the Application, underneath it, the list of the API of this application, repeat the process for all of them. Right now, with my API.map in my return, every API is assigned to the first Application, and repeat itself for the other. Do you have an idea how to "fix" that ?

Comment: It's easy, you just need to change structure of  `APIs`

Comment: Edited answer with new case

Comment: Oh almost ! I got an error "APIs[application.IDAPPLI] is undefined". I did update my APIs useState. I check if I didn't write something wrong.

Comment: Yup, you can add condition like `APIs[application.IDAPPLI] && APIs[application.IDAPPLI].map((api, index) => (`

Comment: Oh yeah you right, I have some API that doesn't have an application so of course is going to send me a undefine warnings ! I don't know what to say, you helped me so much, for more than 3hours.  I hope you will have a very nice days ahaha ^^